# CCLayer is null

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to change the color of a CCLayerColor called bgColorLayer, however when I check to see if it is initialized it returns null.  I have a color picker that calls the `setBGColor:` method. I know the colorpicker is calling the method and it is spitting out the correct colors. I am just at a loss as to why the bgColorLayer is null.

This is Cocos2D for Mac.

Any thoughts on why?

In my AppDelegeate method I have an IBOUTLET that is is tied to the NSColorWell

```
- (IBAction)colorwellBackground:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Color Well: %@", [sender color]);
    // Yes I know the sender color isn’t passing the correct value
    AnimationViewerLayer * bkg = [AnimationViewerLayer alloc];
    [bkg setBGColor:[sender color]];
}
```

**AnimationViewerLayer.h**

```
@interface AnimationViewerLayer : CCLayer
{
  CCLayerColor * bgColorLayer;
}
+ (CCScene *) scene;
@end
```

**AnimationViewLayer.m**

```
    #import "AnimationViewerLayer.h"
    @implementation AnimationViewerLayer

    +(CCScene *) scene
    {
        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
        AnimationViewerLayer *layer = [AnimationViewerLayer node];
        [scene addChild: layer];
        return scene;
    }

    -(id) init
    {
        if( (self=[super init])) {
            float red = 25.0 * 255;
            bgColorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(57, 109, 58, 255)];
            [self addChild:bgColorLayer z:1];     
    }
        return self;
    }

    - (void) setBGColor: (ccColor3B) color{
        NSLog(@"SET BG COLOR");
        [bgColorLayer setColor:ccRED];
    }


    - (void) dealloc {
        [super dealloc];
    }
    @end
```

Comment: Any reason you're not sending an `init` selector to `AnimationViewLayer` in `colorwellBackground:`?

Comment: I have tried many different initializations. The method is getting called when I change the NSColorWell. I even NSLog the bgColorLayer and it pops out <CCLayerColor = 01D85320 | Tag = -1> but the color never changes.

Comment: If I AnimationViewerLayer * bkg = [[AnimationViewerLayer alloc] init] in my AppDelegate, it creates a new instance of the bkg. and it doesn't change the one that is on screen. @jeffamaphone

Comment: why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: What does using ARC have to do with the fact that either my pointer is null or not pointing to the correct layer? And I don't mean that in a hateful way, just wanting to know the reasoning.I was always under the impression from everything I read that ARC deals with garbage collection and cleaning up memory. @LearnCocos2D

Comment: Also the reason I am not using ARC is because the version of Cocos2d 2.0 I have isn't ARC compatible. @LearnCocos2D

Comment: Just every once in a while I keep reminding users that they're doing themselves a disservice by not using ARC, that's all. Especially since it's been out for 2.5 years and there's no reason not to use ARC whatsoever. Probably not related to the issue though. Any cocos2d 2.x version is ARC compatible. Btw, try running an Analyze build if you don't get any warnings/errors, sometimes the analyzer can help you point out the really nasty issues the compiler doesn't complain about.

Comment: Thanks @LearnCocos2D are there any easy to read or quick documents that might help me use Analyze build? Something that most people wont be like "tl;dr" ?

Comment: After running the Analyze build, I got the following message in the colorwellBackground
'Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'bkg' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1' What is the non-arc method to reference the bkg that initialized. Then if I did use ARC, how would it even know which one I wanted to use?